# glVertexAttribDivisor not present

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad

The function `glVertexAttribDivisor` when used with CMake - it just throws the following error during compilation, which means that function is not imported.

`error: 'glVertexAttribDivisor' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'glVertexAttrib4iv'`

I am currently using GLAD for loading openGL, like below:

```
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL context" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

int gladInitRes = gladLoadGL();
if (!gladInitRes) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize glad\n");
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return nullptr;
}
```

And `printf("OpenGL version %i.%i\n", GLVersion.major, GLVersion.minor);` prints out `OpenGL version 4.2`

Comment: Where is the GLAD header, and is the function declared there?

Comment: How do I make sure it is declared there? It doesn't seem like atm

Comment: Look at the file and search for the name of the function.

Comment: Its not there!!

Comment: Sooo - should I try to get a different version of glm or something??

Comment: GLM is a math library; it has nothing to do with this. And if the function isn't part of the loader (aka: GLAD), then you didn't generate the loader's header file correctly.

Comment: Ahh! Well that could be possible as the my source of GLAD is from the internet. And yes sorry for the glm :) - it gets confusing ngl - everything is GL. I will look into generating a new one. Thanks!